# Concatenar resultado de select

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com uma dificuldade para mostrar o resultado do `select` da maneira que quero. Vou explicar primeiro o que tenho e depois o que quero, tenho duas tabelas no banco de dados:

> produto_tipo: id_produto_tipo, tipo_produto e produto_marca:
>   id_produto_marca e nome_mmarca.

Fiz o `select` unindo as duas tabelas para que me mostrasse o resultado das duas:

```
<select name="carne">
    <option value="vazio">
   </option> 
<?php 
$sql = "(select tipo_produto from produto_tipo) 
  union (select nome_marca from produto_marca)";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
 <option value=" <?php echo $linha['tipo_produto'].$linha['nome_marca']; ?> ">
<?php echo utf8_decode($linha['tipo_produto'].$linha['nome_marca']); ?>
</option> 
<?php } ?>  
</select>
```

Até ai tudo bem, mas ela não está mostrando o resultado concatenado. Está mostrando assim:

```
arroz
tio jõao
urbano
```

Preciso que mostre assim:

```
arroz  tio joão
arroz  urbano
```

Sendo que o resultado da primeira parte (`arroz`) vem de uma tabela e o resultado da segunda parte (`tio joao`) vem da segunda tabela.

Comment: Você que alterar só o texto que aparece para o usuário ou o value também?

Comment: apenas o texto do resultado

Comment: Isso acontece porque está fazendo `union select`. Use `join`. Não posto resposta porque está sem informação sobre como é o relacionamento entre as tabelas. Poste a estrutura de ambas as tabelas.

Comment: Até onde pesquisei com o Join eu precisaria de algo que ligasse as duas tabelas, e elas são totalmente independentes

Comment: Então não tem o que fazer. rsrs.. Como você vai saber que a marca A, B ou C pertence ao produto X ou produto Y? Tem que ter algo que os relacione, né. rsrsr

Comment: Se são independentes faça um cross join... mas isso pode ficar um tanto gigante :)

Comment: Coloca a estrutura das duas tabela e o resultado que espera que elas tragam. Só um detalhe `UNION` não é usado assim, ele junta duas tabelas "iguais" mas serão linhas diferentes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está no`UNION` e na modelagem

O **UNION** server pra unir resultados distintos de 2 ou mais **SELECTS** que podem ser totalmente independentes, sendo que esses resultados vão ser listados em **linhas diferentes** bastando apenas terem respectivamente o mesmo número de colunas com o mesmo tipo de dados    !

Caso você queira que sua query retorne na mesma linha o resultado de uma relação você pode usar o **WHERE**(obsoleto) ou **JOIN**

Considerando as informações que você passou , não existe uma tabela **PRODUTO** e seu desejo é que um tipo de produto tenha várias marcas e uma marca tenha vários tipos de produto formando um relacionamento **MANY to MANY**

Nesse cenário é necessário criar uma terceira tabela somente pra fazer a relação entre os 2 e o código ficaria parecido com:

```
    Select tipo_produto , nome_marca FROM produto_tipo INNER JOIN 
TabelaDeRelacao ON produto_tipo.id_produto_tipo = TabelaDeRelacao.FK_Produto_Tipo INNER 
JOIN  produto_marca on produto_marca.id_produto_marca = TabelaDeRelacao.fk_produto_marca
```

Mas seu exemplo sugere que  ou o nome  **produto_tipo** não está muito apropriado pra sua tabela e deveria ser **produto** , ter um terceiro campo **fk_produto_marca** com referência a tabela **produto_marca** e gerar um relacionamento **ONE to MANY** ( uma marca tem vários produtos e um produto possui uma única marca )

E nesse caso a solução seria :

```
   Select tipo_produto , nome_marca FROM produto_tipo INNER JOIN 
produto_marca ON produto_tipo.fk_produto_marca = produto_marca.id_produto_marca
```

Ou deve haver uma terceira tabela `Produto`( que tem por exemplo , nome, fk_produto_tipo , fk_produto_marca ) formando 2 relacionamentos **ONE to MANY**

```
 select tipo_produto , nome_marca from Produto 
inner join produto_tipo on fk_produto_tipo = id_produto_tipo
inner join produto_marca on fk_produto_marca = id_produto_marca
```

Comment: Eu queria a parte do muitos para muitos mesmo, criei uma tabela de relação e segui o exemplo que deu, funcionou. Obrogada

Comment: Olá john, atualizei sua pergunta, devido a palavra depreciada ter outro sentido, o mais aproximado de deprecated em português seria obsoleto ou descontinuado, no entanto não entendi uma coisa na sua resposta, aonde ouviu dizer que `WHERE` é deprecated?